# I need to know if self hosted wordpress site is tracking users in any ways

Tags: wordpress, tracking

I use disconnect.me plugin to block user tracking codes, when I visit an self hosted wordpress website, the plugin blocks a tracking code called "Automattic".

Where can I find more information on this tracking code? This website is not using jetpack plugin, and I expect no tracking code.

Comment: I don’t know anything about the tracking code, but Automatic is the company that owns (made?) Wordpress: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automattic

Comment: I know Automattic, but disconnect.me obviously thinks there are some tracking codes from them. I can't find any information on disconnect.me website about this topic. I want to know how they are tracking and what they are tracking.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all modern WordPress versions check for [automatic updates in the background](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Automatic_Background_Updates).

You can read more about [how to configure these updates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates) or even disable them in the docs. For example, to disable all automatic updates, define the following constant in **wp-config.php**:

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

Comment: I checked config file, it is disabled, but didn't stop the tracking alert.